# Number of ways to arrange 2 groups such that exactly 1 pair from group 1 is side-by-side

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there of arranging seven green and eight brown bottles in a row, so that exactly one pair of green bottles is side-by-side?

Comment: Hint: Glue two green bottles together, then you have six remaining green objects that need to be placed with eight brown objects so that no two green objects are adjacent.

Comment: @vadim123: You should make that hint an answer: I was about to do so myself.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that bottles of the same colour are indistinguishable.  *Put aside* one green bottle. Let us arrange the remaining $14$ bottles so that no two green are together.

To count the number of ways to do this, write down $8$ $X$'s in a row like this:
$$ X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad X\qquad   X\qquad X$$
These will be the ultimate positions of the browns. The $X$'s determine $9$ "gaps," These are the $7$ ordinary gaps between $X$'s, plus the $2$ end "gaps."

We must **choose** $6$ of these  gaps to put the $6$ greens into. This can be done in $d\binom{9}{6}$ ways.

Finally, choose one of the $6$ greens to put the reserved green next to. That gives a total of 
$$6\binom{9}{6}.$$